# Jenkins, Git Hub Pull Request Builder is 1 commit behind

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ghprb

I am using GHPRB plugin to see if pull requests don't break the master of the main repository. Often, after the initial pull request, the developers push more commits to the request branch, which triggers the plugin as expected. However, it turns out that the commit that the plugin checks out and merges locally into master for building and testing, is not the HEAD of the pull request branch, but 1 commit back.

I use a distributed Jenkins set up, i.e. I have a master and a number of slaves. For each of the machines a separate workspace is created, and the version on the master is up to date with the HEAD of the pull request branch, but it lags on the slaves.

I use the following configuration:

`SCM:

Repo url: .....
Credential: .....
Name: origin
Refspec: +refs/heads/:refs/remotes/origin/ +refs/pull/:refs/remotes/origin/pr/
Branch: ${sha1}


Triggers:
GitHub Pull Request Builder`

Am I doing something wrong?